# Misunderstood, an example from the documentation Pytest authorization

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

I decided to look at Pytest and immediately misunderstood, an example from the documentation, but there is no authorization, the test crashes with a code of 301, can anyone know what is the reason?

```
def test_with_authenticated_client(client, django_user_model):
    username = "TestUser"
    password = "1234567"
    user = django_user_model.objects.create_user(username=username,
                                                 password=password)
    # Use this:
    client.force_login(user)
    response = client.get('/new')
    assert response.status_code == 200

def test_with_authenticated_client2(client):
    username = "user2"
    password = "bar"
    # Or this:
    client.login(username=username, password=password)
    response = client.get('/new')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

with an unauthorized client, expected code 301

```
def test_make_not_authorized_user(client):
    response = client.get('/new')
    assert response.status_code in (302, 301)
```

Comment: Is your app using [Django's auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/)? `client.login()` and `client.force_login()` will not work otherwise.

Comment: of course, I'm using Django. I'm a beginner and tested unittest application, but I read pytest is better tried to try. I understand that my mistake is elementary and stupid but what is it